# Incomplete dataset in Power BI after switching from Google Analytics UA to Google Analytics GA4 to integrate GoolgeAds Data

Tags: powerbi, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

Due to the migration from UA to GA4 we had to use the new version of the Google Analytics connector in Power BI, which in turn uses the Google Analytics Data V1beta API, to integrate Google Ads data in our reporting landscape.
After cross-checking the data with the historic data from the UA connection and the source of truth Google Ads, we noticed that the new connector doesn´t retrieve the complete requested dataset.
The dimensions and metrics we requested are not custom but very basic: Google Ad cost, aggregated by Date, AdGroup and Campaign.

Do you have a solution on how to continue to access this data in its complete form?
Do you think this is a bug, a misconfiguration or a "feature"?

When looking into the Debugging of Power BI it shows that the Method: properties.runReport is executed, which *Returns a customized report of your Google Analytics event data. Reports contain statistics derived from data collected by the Google Analytics tracking code. The data returned from the API is as a table with columns for the requested dimensions and metrics.* (copy paste GA documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport)

I tried to replicate the issue in Google Analytics and succeeded, both when using reports and when using exploratory data analysis.

Interestingly when you aggregate the data to Google Ads campaign, the full correct total is shown.

**Hypothesis/Assumption:**
I suspect that this is a "feature" related to GA4's data threshold and not a connector bug.

However, this does not explain to me that the same dimension and metric selection has not been an issue while using Universal Analytics.

Furthermore the "data thresholds" feature exists to prevent anyone viewing a report or exploration from inferring the identity of individual users, but given the selection of dimensions and metrics this shouldn´t be a factor when requesting the data via Power BI.